# changing user's destination, using ISBN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

I would like to make my users create only one page for each book(based on ISBN).But I have no idea how to realize this. Could you give me some advice?

Now, in my system, at first, user search books with the keywords such as book title.
And the index page shows the search result(amazon API).

Since I set up "register button" besides each book(search result), user can create a page for the book and communicate with other users in the page.

☆index.html(index controller)

```
<% if @items.present? %>
  <ul style="list-style: none;">
   <% @items.each do |i| %>
     <li style="clear: both;">
      <div style="width: 150px;float: left;text-align:center;">
        <%= link_to i.get('DetailPageURL') do %>
          <%= image_tag i.get('SmallImage/URL'), {:style => 'border: none;'} %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 150px; float: left;"><%= i.get('ItemAttributes/Title') %><br/>
        <%= i.get('ItemAttributes/Author') %><br/><%= i.get('ItemAttributes/PublicationDate')%>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 150px; float: left;">|<%= link_to 'Register', {:controller => 'groups', :action => 'new', :name => i.get('ItemAttributes/Title'),:author => i.get('ItemAttributes/Author'), :publish => i.get('ItemAttributes/Publisher'), :published => i.get('ItemAttributes/PublicationDate'), :isbn => i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN'), :page => i.get('ItemAttributes/NumberOfPages'), :imageurl=>i.get('MediumImage/URL')}%>|</div>
      </li>
    <% end %> 
   </ul>
  <% else %>
 見つかりませんでした。
 <% end %>
```

☆index_controller

```
def index
@keyword = params[:keyword]
 if @keyword.present?
  Amazon::Ecs.debug = true
  res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search(params[:keyword], 
      :search_index => 'All', :response_group => 'Medium')
  @items = res.items
 end
end
```

But as I said, I don't want to users to make multiple pages for one book. One book(ISBN) has one page. So, I would like to users to move to the existing page when the search encounters the existing page. Otherwise, users would be allowed to create new page on new.html.erb(Groups).

How to realize this? I would like to users to move to new.html.erb when users push the register button beside the book which has no existing page on my system . On the other hand, I would like to users to move to the existing book page when users push the register button beside the book which has the existing page on my system. I would like to make use of ISBN.

☆new.html.erb(Groups)

```
<%= form_for(@group) do |f| %>
  <% if @group.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@group.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this group from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @group.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 <%= image_tag @group.imageurl %>
<p></p>

<table class="table">
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th>著者</th>
   <th>出版年</th>
   <th>出版社</th>
   <th>ページ数</th>
   <th>ISBN</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><%= @group.author %></td>
  <td><%= @group.published %></td>
  <td><%= @group.publish %></td>
  <td><%= @group.page %></td>
  <td><%= @group.isbn %></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

  <div class="field">
    <%#= f.label :name %><br />
    <%#= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%#= f.label :memo %><br />
    <%#= f.text_area :memo ,:class=>"span6", :size=>"5x8"%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit value: 'この本のページをつくる'%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

☆Groups_controller

```
def new
  @group = Group.new
  @group.imageurl = params[:imageurl]
  @group.name = params[:name]
  @group.author = params[:author]
  @group.publish = params[:publish]
  @group.published = params[:published]
  @group.isbn = params[:isbn]
  @group.page = params[:page]
  @group.save

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @group }
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: items.map should now work with Amazon Search API result items.

Seems like in the search index controller where you set @items, you will also need to send along an array which is the subset of isbns of groups that already exist for that search result.

So your search index controller will include something like

```
search_isbns = @items.map{|i| i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN')}
# the WHERE clause passes an array of ISBN values, which will 
# generate a WHERE isbn IN [isnb values] query
@existing_groups_isbns = Group.select(:isbn).where(:isbn => search_isbns).map(&:isbn)
```

And in your search index view code, expand the Register link to be something like

```
<% if @existing_groups_isbns.include? i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN') %>
   # render link_to existing page
<% else %>
   # render link_to register
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.Wilhelm. Now I am trying to figuring out your advice. And I add the code of index_controller.

Comment: Changed the code to make it a bit more clear and should work with Amazon search API results.

Comment: yeah, exactly. I revised your old code like the new one and made it!! Many thanks.